# how to link to url in service from itemclick handler mx:list

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

so this one has stupped me cant find a good explanation anywhere, so i have a php service which provides an array of objects in binary back to my flash application. the service is fed into an mx:list, the sevice has 4 fields **countrycode, citycode, city, and url.** what i need to do is to call the url for each object and feed it to this itemClickHandler this is what i have tried plus the other two others on RIAstar's answer what am i doing wrong here?,

```
protected function citylist_itemClickHandler(event:ListEvent):void
    {
        var data:City = citylist.selectedItem as City;
        navigateToURL(new URLRequest(data.url));

    }
```

this is the mx:list with getCitysResult as the objects

```
    <mx:List includeIn="data" x="28" y="10" width="312" height="255" id="citylist" dataProvider="{getCitysResult.lastResult}" labelField="city" itemClick="citylist_itemClickHandler(event)">
    </mx:List>
```

what i need to do is get each row of this list to have a url link for the Mouse click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ListEvent` has a property [rowIndex](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/events/ListEvent.html#rowIndex) which carries the index of the row that was just clicked. You can use this index to retrieve the correct element from the dataProvider.

```
var city:City = cityList.dataProvider.getItemAt(event.rowIndex) as City;
navigateToURL(new URLRequest(city.url));
```

or directly on the service result object (which is the same, since it's bound):

```
var city:City = getCitysResult.lastResult.getItemAt(event.rowIndex) as City;
```

(unless that lastResult object is an Array: then it would be `getCitysResult.lastResult[event.rowIndex]`)

or (the shortest way) use the List's [selectedItem](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBase.html#selectedItem) property:

```
var city:City = cityList.selectItem as City;
```